# Flashing Coral Dev Board Micro fails with OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: /home/.../third_party/nxp/elftosb/linux/amd64/elftosb

Tags: google-coral

**Product**: Coral Dev Board Micro

**Host Platform**: Raspberry Pi v4 B 8GB

**Host OS**: Raspberry Pi bullseye

**Host Architecture**: aarch64

I'm setting up a development environment for the Coral Dev Board Micro on a Raspberry Pi as described [here](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board-micro/get-started/#4-set-up-for-freertos-development) and [here](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board-micro/freertos/#create-an-in-tree-project). Everything builds, but when I try to flash the device, flashtool.py returns the error below. I don't run into this problem when I use Mac OS.

I'm grateful for any debugging/troubleshooting suggestions.

```
deiter@raspberrypi:~/dev/coral/coralmicro $ python3 scripts/flashtool.py --app helloWorld
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deiter/dev/coral/coralmicro/scripts/flashtool.py", line 1193, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/deiter/dev/coral/coralmicro/scripts/flashtool.py", line 1027, in main
    elftosb_path) if args.flashloader_path else MakeFlashloader(build_dir, cached_files, elftosb_path)
  File "/home/deiter/dev/coral/coralmicro/scripts/flashtool.py", line 243, in MakeFlashloader
    return MakeFlashloaderFromSrec(srec_path, elftosb_path)
  File "/home/deiter/dev/coral/coralmicro/scripts/flashtool.py", line 265, in MakeFlashloaderFromSrec
    subprocess.check_call([elftosb_path, '-f', 'imx', '-V', '-c', bdfile_path, '-o',
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 368, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 349, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1823, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/deiter/dev/coral/coralmicro/third_party/nxp/elftosb/linux/amd64/elftosb'
```